# Why the local function is same in every call to the outer function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def sort_by_last_letter(strings):
    def last_letter(s):
        return s[-1]
    print(last_letter)
    return sorted(strings, key=last_letter)


sort_by_last_letter(['cat', 'mouse', 'zebra'])
sort_by_last_letter(['cat', 'mouse', 'zebra'])
sort_by_last_letter(['cat', 'mouse', 'zebra'])
sort_by_last_letter(['cat1', 'mouse1', 'zebra1'])
```

OUTPUT:

```
<function sort_by_last_letter.<locals>.last_letter at 0x7f6c2d5b99d8>
<function sort_by_last_letter.<locals>.last_letter at 0x7f6c2d5b99d8>
<function sort_by_last_letter.<locals>.last_letter at 0x7f6c2d5b99d8>
<function sort_by_last_letter.<locals>.last_letter at 0x7f6c2d5b99d8>
```

I thought local function last_letter would be different in each call since a new function last_letter would be created each time def is executed for last_letter

Comment: Even if the `last_letter` function is created newly each time `sort_by_last_letter` is run, it can be created identically with the same id and the same representation.

Answer (score 2):

Although `last_letter` goes out of scope and gets "deleted" as soon as the function `sort_by_last_letter` returns, it does not mean that its memory space is reclaimed by the garbage collection process.

You can explicitly delete the `last_letter` function object and manually reclaim its memory space by calling the `gc.collect` function so that the next newly created `last_letter` function object *may* be created at a different memory address:

```
import gc

def sort_by_last_letter(strings):
    def last_letter(s):
        return s[-1]
    print(last_letter)
    s = sorted(strings, key=last_letter)
    del last_letter
    gc.collect()
    return s

sort_by_last_letter(['cat', 'mouse', 'zebra'])
sort_by_last_letter(['cat', 'mouse', 'zebra'])
sort_by_last_letter(['cat', 'mouse', 'zebra'])
sort_by_last_letter(['cat1', 'mouse1', 'zebra1'])
```

which outputs:

```
<function sort_by_last_letter.<locals>.last_letter at 0x000001C263753940>
<function sort_by_last_letter.<locals>.last_letter at 0x000001C2636A1D30>
<function sort_by_last_letter.<locals>.last_letter at 0x000001C2636A1D30>
<function sort_by_last_letter.<locals>.last_letter at 0x000001C2636A1D30>
```

which as you see the newly created `last_letter` function object in each call may still occupy the same memory space even if the memory space of the previous function object is reclaimed, since it is created with the same data structure.

Answer (score 0):

After the `sort_by_last_letter` finishes, its variables are dropped and the ids they use are available for re-use.

The `last_letter` function is created newly each time `sort_by_last_letter` is run, but as it happens it is created identically with the same id and the same representation.